# Table that is a relation of one field to every other similar field

Tags: mysql

So, I have two tables, tblOwners and tblNonOwners. These tables are filled with users. I need a third table that keeps track of if any one user has 'seen' any other user from the other.

What I though is having a tblSeen that has three records, the userID who is using the app, and the profileID that the user has seen/not seen, and a boolean fldSeen as 0 or 1.

How would I populate these tables automatically? I could create records for each user that signs up, but how do I create a record for every single relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this after some clever googling.

The Query is

```
INSERT INTO tblSeen(UserID, ProfileId)
SELECT 'some_user', pmkID FROM tblOwners
```

This will create as many rows as it can and fill it out, so I just have to do this when the user goes to the page.